# How to sum a count of values in a new column inside a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, count, pivot, pivot-table, calculated-columns

I want to create a Pivot Table which shows two columns counting specific values of the "Type" Table column

- One column counting the "Rec" values
- Another column counting the "Maj NCI + Min NCI" sum of values

[image]

I am expecting to have the following table as a Pivot Table

[image]

I tried by adding the following information in the Pivot Table Setting and obtained the following table

[image]

[image]

I also tried by adding the value twice but i cant add a different filter to each column added

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column with headername NCls to the right of your original data table.
Add this formula in the cells.

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("NCl",D10))=TRUE,D10,"NCl")
```

Replace D10 to the actual value of your table's first data row's Type cell address, and copy down the end of the table.
Use this new column in PivotTable with replacing the Type in Column to NCls.

This is the modified table

[image: This is the modified table]

And this is the result

[image: Result]